# Creating a mini-internet using two consumer grade routers

Tags: networking

I'm asking this out of curiosity more than anything else, but this question has been bugging me for a while so here it is: Since the Internet is really just a collection of networks, connected by routers which bounce traffic around from one network to another using routing algorithms and routing tables, how easy (or hard) would it be to link up two consumer-grade routers (running DD-WRT, perhaps) to create my own "mini-internet"?

Physically I imagine the setup would be very simple - I would connect a computer to one router through the LAN port, another computer to the other router through a LAN port, and then link the routers together through the WAN ports.  My goal would be to get the two computers to be able to communicate with each other even though they're on different LANs.  Ideally I would also be able to assign IP addresses in the public address space to the computers, since it won't be connected to the real Internet.

My question is, how would I need to configure the routers do this?  From what I've read it seems like at the minimum I would need to disable NAT so that each computer has a public IP and set up static routes on both routers so they know about each other, but what other steps would be involved?  I actually have two spare DD-WRT routers so if this is possible at all I'd like to give it a try.

Edit: So judging from the lack of responses I guess this is not something that can be easily done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in that you'll need to disable NAT. You'll also want to disable any PPPoE and use the WAN ports in plain Ethernet mode.

Assuming `C`, `D` and `E` are clients, while `R` and `S` are the routers, and your physical network setup is like this:

```
C (eth0) -- (int0) R (ext0) --- (ext0) S (int0) -- (eth0) D
                             |
                           (eth0)
                             E
```

Let's assign the following address blocks and addresses (no need to use public addresses when there's a whole `/8` block just waiting to be used for things like this):

```
R/s: 10.0/16
C/R: 10.1/16
S/D: 10.2/16

C eth0: 10.1.0.2
R int0: 10.1.0.1
R ext0: 10.0.1.1
S ext0: 10.0.2.1
S int0: 10.2.0.1
D eth0: 10.2.0.2
E eth0: 10.0.0.2
```

In this case, R will need the following routes:

```
10.0/16 dev ext0
10.1/16 dev int0
10.2/16 via 10.0.2.1 dev ext0
```

S will need the following routes:

```
10.0/16 dev ext0
10.1/16 via 10.0.1.1 dev ext0
10.2/16 dev int0
```

The routes for `C` and `D` are pretty simple. For example, C will have the regular

```
10.1/16 dev eth0
default via 10.1.0.1 dev eth0
```

They can easily be pushed via `DHCP` by the routers.

The routes for E are a little more complex, since it needs to decide what gateway to send its packets to:

```
10.0/16 dev eth0
10.1/16 via 10.0.1.1 dev eth0
10.2/16 via 10.0.2.1 dev eth0
```

An "mini-Internet" with just two routers is pretty pointless. Try getting more, ideally with more than two interfaces, create loads of networks (represent networks by a switch/hub, and give them an associated address block) and connect networks to routers at random. Routes will become more interesting, allowing stuff such as load balancing. Once you've gathered some experience, it's time to fire up BGP clients on the routers, to allow automatic setting of the routing tables.

Consumer-grade router web interfaces are not designed for setting up detailed routes like this, so trying to abuse them for the job is a rather pointless exercise; I'd recommend to directly work use the router's command-line interfaces. Consumer-grade routers usually have only two network interfaces ("WAN" and "internal"), so it's impossible to use them to connect more than two networks at once, which makes them a little bit... boring (no decisions what interface to emit an incoming packet on, etc...)

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I understand the configuration a lot better now.  I know enterprise routers are probably better suited for this but I'm just trying to learn the basics, so I think I'll stick with consumer routers until I exhaust their capabilities :P

Comment: even better would be a simple Linux box that has multiple network cards.